# Magento 2 : Need to redirect on custom menu page instead of dashboard after login in admin panel

Tags: adminhtml, admin-panel, magento2.3.1

I want to redirect on custom page instead of dashboard in magento 2 admin panel.

How to redirect that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Go to `Store > Configuration >> Advanced >> Admin >> Startup Page` and set whatever you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign custom existing page as Start up page for admin by following steps:

- Login to admin
- Goto Stores-> Configuration
- Goto tab Advanced then click on Admin
- You will find Startup Page in this navigation
- Select your own page by clicking on checkbox beside the dropdown and
  select your own page here.
- Save the config and flush the cache

Now logout from admin and try to login again.

Comment: Works like charm :) Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding.

Comment: Can you please help me when we logic then, default notification display after successfull login. I want to disable that only notification. Is it possible?

Comment: Which notification you are talking about? System messsges?

Comment: Admin notification is a module so you have to disable it. If you don't want it.

Comment: Yes. @Sukumar For ex. when new magento release at that time, that popup will display when we successfully loggin.

Comment: No Ravi. We should not disable that module. If we disable then,  all admin notification will be disable.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this.
Stores->Configuration->ADVANCED->Admin->Startup Page

Comment: Thanks for help.